# How do I make a Mod type with a variable as a parameter?

Tags: haskell, data-kinds

Here's my partially written Haskell code to search for a number of maximum multiplicative order:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
module Cryptography.WringTwistree.Mix3
  ( mix
  , fiboPair
  , searchDir
  ) where

import Data.Bits
import Data.Word
import qualified Data.Sequence as Seq
import Data.Sequence ((><), (<|), (|>), Seq((:<|)), Seq((:|>)))
import Math.NumberTheory.ArithmeticFunctions
import GHC.TypeLits (Nat)
import Data.Mod
import Math.NumberTheory.Primes

mix :: (Num t,Bits t) => t -> t -> t -> t
mix a b c = xor a mask
  where mask = (a .|. b .|. c) - (a .&. b .&. c)

fibonacci = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibonacci (tail fibonacci)

fiboPair :: Integer -> [Integer]
fiboPair n = take 2 $ dropWhile (<= n) fibonacci

searchDir :: Integer -> (Integer,Int)
-- fst=n/φ rounded to nearest. snd=+1 or -1, indicating search direction.
-- e.g. if n=89, returns (55,1). Search 55,56,54,57,53...
-- if n=144, returns (89,(-1)). Search 89,88,90,87,91...
searchDir n
  | r*2 < den = (q,1)
  | otherwise = (q+1,(-1))
  where [num,den] = fiboPair (2*n)
        (q,r) = (n*num) `divMod` den

isMaxOrder :: Integral a => Nat -> a -> [a] -> a -> Bool
-- isMaxOrder modl car fac n
-- where modl is the modulus, car is its Carmichael function,
-- fac is the set of prime factors of car (without multiplicities),
-- and n is the number being tested.
-- Returns true if n has maximum order, which implies it's a primitive root
-- if modulus has any primitive roots.
isMaxOrder modl car fac n = (modln ^% car) == modl1 && allnot1
  where modln = (fromIntegral n) :: Mod modl
        modl1 = 1 :: Mod modl
        powns = map ((modln ^%) . (car `div`)) fac
        allnot1 = foldl (&&) True (map (/= modl1) powns)
```

I try to compile this and get these errors:

```
/home/phma/src/wring-twistree/src/Cryptography/WringTwistree/Mix3.hs:43:36: error:
    • Could not deduce (GHC.TypeNats.KnownNat m0)
        arising from a use of ‘^%’
      from the context: Integral a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   isMaxOrder :: forall a. Integral a => Nat -> a -> [a] -> a -> Bool
        at /home/phma/src/wring-twistree/src/Cryptography/WringTwistree/Mix3.hs:36:1-56
      The type variable ‘m0’ is ambiguous
    • In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘(modln ^% car)’
      In the first argument of ‘(&&)’, namely ‘(modln ^% car) == modl1’
      In the expression: (modln ^% car) == modl1 && allnot1
   |
43 | isMaxOrder modl car fac n = (modln ^% car) == modl1 && allnot1
   |                                    ^^

/home/phma/src/wring-twistree/src/Cryptography/WringTwistree/Mix3.hs:44:18: error:
    • Could not deduce (GHC.TypeNats.KnownNat modl1)
        arising from a use of ‘fromIntegral’
      from the context: Integral a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   isMaxOrder :: forall a. Integral a => Nat -> a -> [a] -> a -> Bool
        at /home/phma/src/wring-twistree/src/Cryptography/WringTwistree/Mix3.hs:36:1-56
      Possible fix:
        add (GHC.TypeNats.KnownNat modl1) to the context of
          an expression type signature:
            forall (modl1 :: Nat). Mod modl1
    • In the expression: (fromIntegral n) :: Mod modl
      In an equation for ‘modln’: modln = (fromIntegral n) :: Mod modl
      In an equation for ‘isMaxOrder’:
          isMaxOrder modl car fac n
            = (modln ^% car) == modl1 && allnot1
            where
                modln = (fromIntegral n) :: Mod modl
                modl1 = 1 :: Mod modl
                powns = map ((modln ^%) . (car `div`)) fac
                allnot1 = foldl (&&) True (map (/= modl1) powns)
   |
44 |   where modln = (fromIntegral n) :: Mod modl
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^

/home/phma/src/wring-twistree/src/Cryptography/WringTwistree/Mix3.hs:45:17: error:
    • Could not deduce (GHC.TypeNats.KnownNat modl1)
        arising from the literal ‘1’
      from the context: Integral a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   isMaxOrder :: forall a. Integral a => Nat -> a -> [a] -> a -> Bool
        at /home/phma/src/wring-twistree/src/Cryptography/WringTwistree/Mix3.hs:36:1-56
      Possible fix:
        add (GHC.TypeNats.KnownNat modl1) to the context of
          an expression type signature:
            forall (modl1 :: Nat). Mod modl1
    • In the expression: 1 :: Mod modl
      In an equation for ‘modl1’: modl1 = 1 :: Mod modl
      In an equation for ‘isMaxOrder’:
          isMaxOrder modl car fac n
            = (modln ^% car) == modl1 && allnot1
            where
                modln = (fromIntegral n) :: Mod modl
                modl1 = 1 :: Mod modl
                powns = map ((modln ^%) . (car `div`)) fac
                allnot1 = foldl (&&) True (map (/= modl1) powns)
   |
45 |         modl1 = 1 :: Mod modl
   |                 ^

/home/phma/src/wring-twistree/src/Cryptography/WringTwistree/Mix3.hs:46:29: error:
    • Could not deduce (GHC.TypeNats.KnownNat m1)
        arising from a use of ‘^%’
      from the context: Integral a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   isMaxOrder :: forall a. Integral a => Nat -> a -> [a] -> a -> Bool
        at /home/phma/src/wring-twistree/src/Cryptography/WringTwistree/Mix3.hs:36:1-56
      The type variable ‘m1’ is ambiguous
      Relevant bindings include
        powns :: [Mod m1]
          (bound at /home/phma/src/wring-twistree/src/Cryptography/WringTwistree/Mix3.hs:46:9)
    • In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘(modln ^%)’
      In the first argument of ‘map’, namely ‘((modln ^%) . (car `div`))’
      In the expression: map ((modln ^%) . (car `div`)) fac
   |
46 |         powns = map ((modln ^%) . (car `div`)) fac
   |                             ^^
```

The parameters to `isMaxOrder` are positive integers and a list of positive integers. I first tried making `modl` of type `a`, then tried `Nat` (and importing `GHC.TypeLits` unqualified resulted in a conflict of `mod` or something). I can type `1 :: Mod 89` and it works, but `1 :: Mod (fromIntegral 89)` results in an error.

Comment: Notice `Mod` has a type-level natural as a parameter. You are trying to use a term-level Integer, which doesn't work because they don't belong to the same name space. In other word, you can write `5 :: Mod 10` to represent  five within the ciclic group of order 10, but in that expresion `5` is an integer value but `10` is a type(!!) not a value. Hence you can't do things like `5 :: Mod (5 + 5)`, because you can't add `type 5 plus type 5` (unless you use type level functions.)

Comment: The been said I think `isMaxOrder :: (Integral a,  KnownNat modl) => a -> [a] -> a -> Bool` and then `modln = n :: Mod modl` . Notice `modl` becomes a type-level entity. Be aware, once you get into type level programming, you'll have to activate dozens of extension, and the compiler will throw terrible errors, and the ergonomics are just insanely difficult... If the library is well desing, you may avoid many problems... but just keep that in mind

Comment: So how do I turn an integer, which I get by dividing the message length by 3, into a `KnownNat`? This is the only function that uses natural numbers as types; the other functions (which I haven't written yet) just use them as numbers.

Comment: I am not very confident with type level programming., but I'd say you simply can't. The whole point of `KnownNat` is that it is a `Nat` known at compile time. For this use cases, I think you can rely on `SomeNat` from `GHC.TypeLits`... but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Okay, is there a way to raise a to the bth power mod c without using type-level programming?

Comment: Sure!, you can use `rem` which is the reminder function. so `modPower a b c = (a ^ b) \`rem\` c ` (notice, a more efficient algorithm is posible)

Comment: Can't do that. The numbers could be in the billions.

Comment: In `GHC.Natural` there is a `powModNatural` function  which apparently is fast modular exponentiation. But It doesn't work with negative numbers... if it doesn't fit your use case, you should look for a different library/solution.

Comment: `powModNatural` works.

Comment: Your current code doesn't really use type-numbers at all. I suggest you take a look at [the modular-arithmetic package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/modular-arithmetic-2.0.0.3/docs/Data-Modular.html) to get used to what that would entail.

Answer (score 1):

You need [`modulo`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.12.1.0/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Moduli-Class.html#t:modulo).

```
isMaxOrder modl car fac n = case (modulo n modl, modulo 1 modl) of
    (SomeMod modln, SomeMod modl1) -> ...
```

You can also use the resulting `SomeMod`s without unwrapping them first if you like. All the usual typeclass instances are available.